# node.js and front-end js return different date formats

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, format

I have a node.js web app and I ran into a problem with date formats.

```
console.log(new Date());
```

With node.js, this prints

> 2019-10-12T22:05:07.019Z

But when ran in chrome (or any other browser), this prints

> Sat Oct 12 2019 15:05:03 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

The difference in time is because of time zones or something, I don't care about that. But the formats are very different.
How do I make the two Dates return the same format?

Comment: `console.log(new Date());` will call `Date#toString` which is implementation-dependant.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the execution environments - The browser prints the `local datetime`, whereas nodejs is printing the `UTC`

[Read Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString)

> The toUTCString() method converts a date to a string, using the UTC time zone.

you can use `new Date().toUTCString()` to get the same format in both environments

Comment: Node.js seems to be using [*toISOString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), not *toUTCString*. Another option is to use `console.log(new Date().toString())` in both environments (or any explicit *to\*String* method). ;-)